# How to associate a subclass with XML file?

Tags: android, xml, subclass

I have an XML file describing a dialog that contains a button, images, and text. In order to override the onClick and get it called for all the widgets in a dialog I wrote a subclass that extends RelativeLayout. Now I would like to associate the XML file with the subclass. Can I do it without using the inflater?

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="text" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks,
 Simon

Comment: Show the XML file - it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Instead of typing RelativeLayout, use the complete package name for your subclass.

```
  <com.example.MySubclassRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      ...
  </com.example.MySubclassRelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put these widget into  a layout for example dialogwidgets.xml, then you can use include tag to insert this all layout which ever you want

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/dialogwidgets"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```